# Tensor Products and the Dual Space

Tags: linear-algebra

***Problem:***

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $K$ of dimension $n$. Show that there exists a unique linear form $L: V^* ⊗  V \rightarrow K$ satisfying the condition $L(f⊗v) = f(v)$ for all $f \in V^∗$ and $v \in V$ .

***Thoughts:***
I have just been introduced to tensor products. From what I understand this amounts to showing that for any map $B: V^* \times V \rightarrow K$ that there exists a unique $L: V^* ⊗ V \rightarrow K$ satisfying $B(f,v) = L(f ⊗ v)$.

What I find confusing is that the questions seems to define $L$ before we consider an arbitrary $B$. For instance what if $B(f,v) = 2f(v)$? Perhaps I am misunderstanding the definitions.

In any case I imagine the answer would be that $L$ is defined on a basis of $V$ and $V^*$ such that $L(f_i ⊗ v_j)$ is the kronecker delta function. Is this correct?

Comment: Choosing $B(f,v)=2f(v)$ would give $L(f\otimes v) = 2f(v)$. It seems to me that finite-dimensional condition is irrelevant.

Comment: @HanulJeon can you explain why that is so?

Comment: As you explained, by universal property, every bilinear map gives the morphism from the tensor product. So your $B(f,v) := f(v)$ gives the desired map.

Comment: If this is part of a longer question, the finite-dimensionality assumption may be to prove that $V^* \otimes V \cong \operatorname{End}(V)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensor product of two $K$-vector spaces $U$ and $V$ is a vector space $U\otimes V$ together with a bilinear map $\tau:U\times V\to U\otimes V$, $t(u,v)=u\otimes v$ such that

> for all $K$-vector spaces $W$ and all bilinear maps $B\colon U\times V\to W$, there exists a unique linear map $L\colon U\otimes V\to W$ with $L\circ\tau=B$.

In your case, $U=V^*$, $W=K$ and $B(f,v)=f(v)$. The property stated before says that $L(f\otimes v)=L(\tau(f,v))=B(f,v)=f(v)$.

If you consider $B'(f,v)=2f(v)$, the linear map $L'$ you get satisfies $L'(f\otimes v)=2f(v)$.

If you prefer to use bases, then, if $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$ and $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ is its dual basis, then indeed.
$$
L(f_i\otimes v_j)=\delta_{ij}
$$